# Personal finance application with share management

Tags: finance

One day, I was thinking of a better way to manage my finance, so I did some search and tried to find a finance application that does what I wanted it to do.

Can someone recommend me an application that satisfies the following requirements:

- Runs on Android or iOS
- Allows adding stock with an auto-updating stock price
- Basic personal finance management
- Basic import and export
- Repeating expenses
- Sync with bank accounts
- Category of expense and revenue

Answer (score 1):

[Mint](https://www.mint.com) is an excellent app that has both desktop and Android interfaces. Intuit has come a long way to improve what they were doing with personal finance applications since 10 years ago. I am not certain; however, if it is able to allow you to access your brokerage account to trade stocks, but I am definitely sure that you can at least monitor these accounts. I know you can move money between accounts and track/categorize your spending and credit accounts and bills and pay bills. The reports for this program are awesome and it also provides projections and guidance with budgeting. I was able to connect all of my accounts online that had online access with the only downside that one or two asked for additional security so it took a few more minutes to set up then I would have liked. I believe using the application itself is free and they also offer services in addition to what I mentioned for a fee.

Answer (score 0):

YNAB - You Need A Budget.
Give it a try.

https://www.ynab.com/

It is not just a software. It is building a habit of controlling the spending and you can save more.
It is based on the idea of 'Give every dollar a job'. One of the thing I liked most with YNAB is that there are plenty of videos available. Also they have good customer support.

Due to all the above stuffs, it is little bit expensive ( $99 per annum)

Comment: Hello Rauf!  Please post a link to the software you are recommending, and please explain how it meets the requirements specified by the question.  Thanks!